# Use instance after binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class called **MyClass** with a property called **Density** located in main window and binded to a textbox in another window called **Material**. I binded textbox with a property because, as far as I know, I cannot bind it with an instance. OK, now I want to use the instance, I mean I want to get instance Density when I close the Material dialog to use it for calculations.  How can I do this?

**EDIT: Added some code:**

**Main Window:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string num;

    public string Density
    {
        get { return num; }
        set { num = value; }
    }
}
```

**Material Window: Some portion of XAML:**

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,27,0,0" Name="txt_density"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"  Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBox}" TextChanged="txt_density_TextChanged">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Density" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:Float_Positive_ValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Here I want to use density to make some calculations as I cannot do that with a class.

Comment: Can you please post some of the code in question?

Comment: A few points in your question are unclear: What do you mean by "class Density *located* in the main window"? Why do you mean by "cannot bind it with an instance"? Maybe you should add a *short* code example to illustrate your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making assumptions that your actual `Window` implementation is called "Material" as implied by your post.

**UPDATE:**

Edited after seeing your code.

In your calling code:

```
Material dialog = new Material();

    if (dialog.ShowDialog())
    {
       string density = dialog.Density;
    }
```

In your `Material` window code:

```
public string Density
{
   get { return txt_density.Text;
}
```